# Plot the nodes of the shortest path found by dijkstra algorithm

Tags: qgis, pgrouting

I am using qgis and pgrouting plugin to find the shortest path between two nodes and display the route. Currently, the plot shows the shortest path. However, I also want to know which nodes the path passes through. So is it possible to actually get this information?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are using Postgresql, PostGIS and pgrouting.

pgrouting returns a result set of nodes that represent the nodes within the shortest path.

A simple way to plot this in qgis is to save the shortest path result set into a table in postgresql (use an select into statement).

Once you have the table in postgresql, you will be add that table as a separate layer in your project.

Comment: I just have a set of nodes that I need to plot on the map. I don't have them in the database just a set of nodes like 1-152-2-50 that defines the path for example

Comment: Well I managed to plot the nodes. But I want to know their ids as well. Is there any possible way to visualize their id as well

Comment: How are you plotting the nodes? Did you select the IDs so you can use labeling?